# X-server vs. Wayland vs. Mir

Tags: xorg, wayland, distributions

What is the difference between X-server,  Wayland and Mir? I know X-server is a display server, but what is the role of Wayland and Mir?

Comment: You asked two question one very hard to explain and most likely already answered and one really easy which one is your priority in your two questions ? Its usually better to ask two differents if you have two

Comment: @Kiwy - I have edited